# Using Motor or any other async MongoDB driver in Django 3 projects

Tags: python, django, mongodb, asynchronous

Is there any way using **Motor** or any other **async MongoDB driver** in Django 3 projects?

I tried using motor clients First: `motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient` and Second: `motor_tornado.MotorClient`.

The first one raises below exception:

```
Task <Task pending coro=<SessionMiddlewareInstance.__call__() running at SOMEWHERE>> got Future <Future pending cb=[run_on_executor.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at SOMEWHERE]> attached to a different loop
```

The second one doesn't raise any exceptions but it stops at the line that I insert messages in db with `insert_one` method.

Is there any way to insert and read data from MongoDB asynchronously?

---

Edit: There must be a way to use the `motor_asyncio` client in Django. Does anyone have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: i have same question

Comment: if you're using the motor with Django session manage , the exception concept is true, because is phase two that Django support middleware and views work async, I suggest you create instance `client motor` in setting.py and work with that.